# Where should I put setup codes for android apps

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app which requires to setup predefined database values. For example, I want to run sql codes to set up database tables and insert data into them.

Where should I put my code in the app? It's also acceptable if you can show me how to run those codes every time the app is started.

Answer (score 1):

[OnCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method of your [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Comment: (+1)It is the best place for creation of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that you want to be executed when the app starts app should be put in the [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) of the respective [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). This way it'll run everytime the Activity is started. Note that this means it'll also run on orientation changes, unless you handle them yourself.

If you only want the code to run the first time an app launches, you could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store a boolean and enclose the code in an if-else block like:

boolean runOnce = prefs.getBoolean("runOnce", false);

```
//Pseudocode
    if(!runOnce)
    {
       //run code
       prefsEditor.putBoolean("runOnce", true);
       prefsEditor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Your direction seems to be right. But it doesn't quite make enough sense. What you're saying is that a control flag should be used. Using the flag, we can decide how many time the enclosed code should be run. Hence, in my opinion, there should be this line "prefsEditor.putBoolean("runOnce", false) at the end when the user switches off the app right?

Comment: I'm saying that you can use a SharedPrefs flag if you want the code to run only once. If you want it to run everytime, simply omit the if statement